# Performance implications of using several F# type providers at once

Tags: f#, type-providers

In my project, I am currently using SqlCommandProvider for the simple SQL cases, and SqlDataConnection with FSharpComposableQuery for the more complex, dynamic SQL queries. Will this result in extra performance overhead, as opposed to using only one type provider for SQL?

Comment: I'd suggest writing your SQL queries into files. Benchmark it against running those same queries with the TPs.